# Password Hashing with SQL Server 2008 CLR

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, hash, password-hash

I'm attempting to implement a solution to hash and salt a password in SQL Server 2008 using the SHA-512 algorithm. This solution is based on the book "Expert SQL Server 2008 Encryption" by Michael Coles. Based on his examples, I am able to build the project in visual studio 2010 (.NET 3.5 in C#) and deploy to SQL Server 2008 (as shown in the code below).

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Apress.Samples
{
    public partial class CustomEncryption
    {
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction
    (
      IsDeterministic = true,
      DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None
    )]
    public static SqlBytes SaltedHash
    (
      SqlString Algorithm,
      [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] SqlBytes PlainText,
      SqlBytes Salt
    )
    {
        // Return NULL if any of the parameters is NULL
        if (Algorithm.IsNull || PlainText.IsNull || Salt.IsNull)
            return SqlBytes.Null;

        // Determine which algorithm to use
        bool HashDefined = true;
        HashAlgorithm Hash = null;
        switch (Algorithm.Value.ToUpper())
        {
            case "SHA256":
                Hash = new SHA256Managed();
                break;

            case "SHA384":
                Hash = new SHA384Managed();
                break;

            case "SHA512":
                Hash = new SHA512Managed();
                break;

            default:
                HashDefined = false;
                break;
        }
        if (!HashDefined)
            throw new Exception
              ("Unsupported hash algorithm - use SHA256, SHA384 or SHA512");

        // Combine the plaintext with the salt
        byte[] PlainTextWithSalt = new byte[PlainText.Length + Salt.Length];
        for (long i = 0; i < Salt.Length; i++)
            PlainTextWithSalt[i] = Salt[i];
        for (long i = Salt.Length; i < PlainText.Length; i++)
            PlainTextWithSalt[i] = PlainText.Value[i - Salt.Length];

        // Generate the hash and return the result
        byte[] HashBytes = Hash.ComputeHash(PlainTextWithSalt);
        return new SqlBytes(HashBytes);
    }
}
}
```

When I perform a test from SQL using the code below, the hash is generated as expected for each algorithm.

```
DECLARE @plaintext varchar(15);
SET @plaintext = 'ABCDEFGHIJ';

DECLARE @salt varbinary(16);
SET @salt = Crypt_Gen_Random(16);

DECLARE @sha256 varbinary(32)
DECLARE @sha384 varbinary(48)
DECLARE @sha512 varbinary(64)

SELECT @sha256 = dbo.SaltedHash('SHA256', CAST(@plaintext AS varbinary(max)), @salt);
SELECT @sha384 = dbo.SaltedHash('SHA384', CAST(@plaintext AS varbinary(max)), @salt);
SELECT @sha512 = dbo.SaltedHash('SHA512', CAST(@plaintext AS varbinary(max)), @salt);

SELECT 'SHA-256' AS algorithm, @sha256 AS hash
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHA-384', @sha384
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHA-512', @sha512;
```

I would like to use this for validating a login, where I'm assuming I would need to retrieve the salt value that is stored for the user record and pass it along to the SaltedHash function, where it would return the hashed value. From there, I would compare the hashed value returned by the function with the hashed value stored in the user record.

The problem I'm encountering is when I test passing a hardcoded salt value ('0x0E5ECC235FF6BD7337FFDDE5799D4EEA'), along with the plaintext ('ABCDEFGHIJ') to simulate retrieving the hashed value (for comparing hashed passwords for example). If I provide the plaintext value of ('1234567890') with the same hardcoded salt value, it returns the exact same hashed value. Actually, any 10 character plaintext value returns the same hashed value.

```
DECLARE @plaintext varchar(15);
SET @plaintext = 'ABCDE12345';

DECLARE @salt varbinary(16);
SET @salt = 0x0E5ECC235FF6BD7337FFDDE5799D4EEA; // Hardcoded salt value!

SELECT @salt

DECLARE @sha256 varbinary(32)
DECLARE @sha384 varbinary(48)
DECLARE @sha512 varbinary(64)

SELECT @sha256 = dbo.SaltedHash('SHA256', CAST(@plaintext AS varbinary(max)), @salt);
SELECT @sha384 = dbo.SaltedHash('SHA384', CAST(@plaintext AS varbinary(max)), @salt);
SELECT @sha512 = dbo.SaltedHash('SHA512', CAST(@plaintext AS varbinary(max)), @salt);

SELECT 'SHA-256' AS algorithm, @sha256 AS hash
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHA-384', @sha384
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHA-512', @sha512;
```

I'm assuming the problem lies with the "combining the plaintext with the salt" code, but unsure.

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just note that if the salt is hardcoded in your final solution it is not a salt. That would be a [Pepper](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough), salts are unique per password, you would normally just store the salt in the next column over or concat it to the front or back of the bytearray of the cyphertext.

Comment: Thanks for that note, as I wasn't familiar with a 'Pepper'. My intentions are to create a unique salt per password as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you made a error with the array copy, you never copy the last `Salt.Length` bytes of `PlainText` in to the destination array. Here is a corrected version of your original code. All that needed to be done is `i` needs to go up to `PlainText.Length + Salt.Length`

```
// Combine the plaintext with the salt
byte[] PlainTextWithSalt = new byte[PlainText.Length + Salt.Length];
for (long i = 0; i < Salt.Length; i++)
    PlainTextWithSalt[i] = Salt[i];
for (long i = Salt.Length; i < PlainText.Length + Salt.Length; i++)
    PlainTextWithSalt[i] = PlainText.Value[i - Salt.Length];
```

However it is a lot easier to do by using [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx)

```
byte[] PlainTextWithSalt = new byte[PlainText.Length + Salt.Length];
Array.Copy(Salt, PlainTextWithSalt, Salt.Length);
Array.Copy(PlainText, PlainTextWithSalt, Salt.Length, PlainText.Length);
```

---

One other thing to note. Salting your passwords is good, but [that is only half the battle](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/), you also need to make the hashing ***SLOW***. Normally this is done with functions like [bcrypt](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) or [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx), these functions manage mixing the salt and password for you plus they also let you set the number of iterations of hashing to do on the password (you would usually choose a large number, you want the number as large as is tolerable on your end system for slowness).

Comment: I've applied your corrected code and confirmed it is now working. Also, thanks for the homework. I decided to use the CLR/.NET SHA2 method because it seemed to be a solution that's been more widely adopted. But seems like bcrypt is also something I'll invest some time in. The 'tuning' part of bcrypt does seem like an attractive feature.

Comment: @vanexellent PBKDF2 also has that tuning factor built in to it to via it's [ItterationCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.iterationcount.aspx) property (however you will want to use numbers `>10000` for the count to get meaningful slowdown of the algorithm on modern hardware) The nice thing about using tunable work factors is when you get faster hardware and need to make the hash slower just re-hash with a larger factor the next time the user logs in, all you need to do is store the work factor you used last time with the hash and salt

Comment: Thanks, I've done some research on those algorithms and glad to know they can be used from SQL 2008 (.NET 3.5), which is the version we're stuck with for now. Appreciate the help!